# Compare two python pandas dataframe string columns to identify common string and add the common string to new column

Tags: python, pandas, database, compare, matching

I have the following two pandas df:

```
df1:             df2:

item_name        item_cleaned

abc xyz          Def
xuy DEF          Ghi
s GHI lsoe       Abc
p ABc ois
```

I need to write a function to compare `df2.item_cleaned` with `df1.item_name` to see if string in `df2.item_cleaned` exists in `df1.item_name` (non-case sensitive).

Where the string exists (irrespective of case), i want to create a new column `df1.item_final` and input the `df2.item_cleaned` string value in this new column for every row.

Output should look something like this:

```
df1:                                 df2:

item_name        item_final          item_cleaned

abc xyz          Abc                 Def
xuy DEF          Def                 Ghi
s GHI lsoe       Ghi                 Abc
p ABc ois        Abc
```

For reference my df1 that is to be cleaned has 12 columns and about 400,000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a map `obj_map` with key as item_cleaned's lower letters, values is item_cleaned.
2. use regexp to extract tem_cleaned, with flags `re.IGNORECASE`
3. then lower the extract part and replace it with `obj_map` to get `item_final`

```
import re
item_cleaned = df2['item_cleaned'].dropna().unique()
obj_map = pd.Series(dict(zip(map(str.lower, item_cleaned), item_cleaned)))

# escape the special characters
re_pat = '(%s)' % '|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in item_cleaned])

df1['item_final'] = df1['item_name'].str.extract(re_pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df1['item_final'] = df1['item_final'].str.lower().map(obj_map)
```

obj_map

```
def    Def
ghi    Ghi
abc    Abc
dtype: object
```

df1

```
    item_name item_final
0     abc xyz        Abc
1     xuy DEF        Def
2  s GHI lsoe        Ghi
3   p ABc ois        Abc
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. This gives me the following error:

error: bad character range E-1 at position 2201

Any idea how i can fix that?

Comment: your item_cleaned has some special characters, see in  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, you should escape them first in the `re_pat` string.

Comment: Worked. Thanks so much. Been trying to figure this out since a long time.

Comment: I've ran into a problem:

If I have `"AZITHROMYCIN DIHYDRYTE ABCD"` and  `"AZITHROMYCIN DEFG"` in my  `item_name` column, i naturally have both  `"AZITHROMYCIN"` and  `"AZITHROMYCIN DIHYDRYTE"` in my  `item_cleaned` column to match appropiate names.

When i run this all  `"AZITHROMYCIN DIHYDRYTE ABCD"` is matched and replaced with  `"AZITHROMYCIN"` since its higher up in the  `item_cleaned` column without considering the full item name. Any way to solve this?

Comment: sort item_cleaned by its length, place the longer one in front